# LESS syntax highlighting for emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, less

Does anyone know of a syntax file to get LESS working in emacs?

Comment: Ah, you're talking about http://lesscss.org/ ?

Comment: Yeap, Dan's answer was exactly what I was looking for. Searching for 'less' is a somewhat difficult thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for a [less-css emacs mode](http://jdhuntington.com/emacs/less-css-mode.el), which is an `elisp` file that can be loaded in your `emacs` environment. Another version is also available in [github](https://github.com/purcell/less-css-mode/).